# Give moderators more influence over the FAQs

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request, moderator-tools

Moderators are allowed to edit the section between

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> User Experience - Stack Exchange is for user experience researchers and designers.

and

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before.  It’s also OK to ask and 
>   answer your own question.
>
> ### What kind of questions should I not ask here?

That makes it hard to address the true questions that people have and still fit into the template.

1. Adding new questions is technically possible, but making the last two sentences fit with the last question is awkward.
2. We can't edit the section under "What kind of questions should I not ask here," and that's what most often comes up as lacking from the FAQ.

Please consider allowing moderators a little bit more influence over the FAQs for their individual sites. My preference would be to **make the entire FAQ customizable, with site moderators having the ability to *suggest* edits for review by Community Moderators.**

Comment: Agreed, at the very least I've noticed that on UX.SE and DBA.SE there are some "don't ask" criteria that belong only for those sites. For example on DBA questions Basic SQL and any questions that involve SQL *relating to a programming language* don't belong. This fits with "don't ask" but not so much "do ask" these questions. On UX.SE "implementation" questions about programming don't belong but that doesn't fit as nicely under "do ask".

Comment: English.SE has a great way of dealing with this issue, they added subheadings http://english.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the FAQ — the part you can edit — describes what your site is about. The rest is mostly philosophy and the mechanics of *how* the site works. We wouldn't want every site modifying these areas because they are *designed* to be consistent across the network.

It's true that you can help define your site by citing what it is *not* about. To add that information to your FAQ, follow the format of the [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: Side note: mods on SU actually _can't_ edit our own FAQ.